# How to implement screen lock to a react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, security, biometrics

I wish to add a security feature to my mobile application that every time a user opens the app, it shows default screen lock of the device (pin, password, facial recognition, or fingerprint)

Answer (score 0):

You will need local authentication

If you are using expo then you have https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/sdk/local-authentication

Otherwise it can be directly installed using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-local-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using expo, and both of these packages are using expo.

Comment: Both are same library. npm version can be directly used.

Comment: more details are given in the package description.

Comment: you can use expo-local-authentication in a bare react native app just need to add the expo unimodules package as well.

Comment: Is there a way with expo-local-authentication to authenticate the user only against the pattern (android) passcode (ios) cause it seems that you always need to trigger biometrics first? and pattern is only a fallback?

Comment: @HaseebA Hi Haseeb, hope you are good. I am also developing a very similar app and was wondering in my previous projects because they were not secure i was using expo-secure-store to my token but now since i am developing a secure project can you help me understanding the steps i should follow. thank you in advance

Comment: @kd12345 Follow the npmjs link and do the steps mentioned in Installation in bare React Native projects.

Comment: I am using expo managed projects not bare react native projects

Comment: @kd12345 `expo install expo-local-authentication`

Comment: @HaseebA this is used for face ID correct?